# Unable to access Glue tables from Presto EMR

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue, presto, hive-metastore, trino

I've created an EMR (v 5.32) with Spark, Presto, Hadoop, Zeppelin, Hive etc.
I enabled these:

1. Use Glue metadata for Presto
2. Use Glue metadata for Spark

Here are the configurations visible on the EMR console:

```
[
   {
      "classification":"presto-connector-hive",
      "properties":{
         "hive.metastore.glue.datacatalog.enabled":"true"
      },
      "configurations":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "classification":"spark-hive-site",
      "properties":{
         "hive.metastore.client.factory.class":"com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory"
      },
      "configurations":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

The datacatalog is visible in Athena, but whenever a query is run to SELECT from a table, it just times out after staying in QUEUED, 0 nodes are assigned.

```
presto:sampledb> select * from presto_test_cities_test_presto limit 5;
Query 20210120_072228_00019_xx9vu, QUEUED, 0 nodes, 0 splits   //stays on this status for few minutes
// then times out
Query 20210120_072228_00019_xx9vu failed: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 [glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XX.ZZ.YYY.XXX, glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3.XXX.XX.XX, glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XX.XXX.XX.XXX, glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XX.XXX.XX.XXX, glue.us-east-
1.amazonaws.com/XX.XX.XXX.XXX, glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XX.XX.XXX.XX] failed: connect timed out
```

What is missing here? I have used the default `AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role` managed policy attached to `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole`. I tried to query the same data using Athena and it works fine.